# Copy a cell to the cell next to the result of a lookup vba

Tags: excel, vba, copy, lookup

I have a sheet called "containers"
Where I have the following data like this :

[image: sheet "containers"]

On my other sheet "planner" I have a full list of around 900 containers with lots of data.

What i am trying to do is to do a lookup of Column B from my sheet "containers"
And copy the responding value of column A into the field "agreed_unload_hour" of the looked up value.

[image: sheet "planner"]

So basically in this case I would like that for container1 the value 5u00 from sheet "containers" gets pasted to sheet "planner" in the agreed_unload_hour of sheet "planner".
And this for all the containers on the sheet "containers" (a fixed range).

I know I could do this with a formula index/match, but i cant put my formula on sheet "planner" because that is populated with data, and I cant overwrite this data with my formula.
I need it in VBA as it is part of a bigger vba project.

Thank you so much for ending my struggle, as i find a lot of similar things in here, but they always seem to work the other way round, copying data from my sheet "planner" to sheet "containers" like a normal vlookup would do.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question, include your code attempt and explain what is not working with your code in details. SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: In your example, you have the **Column A** value of **Container 1** in all three rows, for **Container1-3**. Is this correct for the **"fixed range"** you are talking about, or should it be directly correlating to the container number? If `AGREED_UNLOAD_HOUR` row 3 isn't supposed to be `7u30` then what is this fixed number, and how is it determined?

Comment: @ChristoferWeber in this example the updated value in AGREED_UNLOAD_HOUR in the sheet PLanner should indeed be for container1 : 5u00, for container2 : 7u30 for container3: 12u30. The existing values should be overwritten indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have only one table on the planner sheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Update()

   Dim arID, arName, i
   Dim lastrow As Long, n As Long
   Dim tbl As ListObject, r As ListRow
   Dim a As Long, b As Long
   
   With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Containers")
       lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
       arID = .Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Value2
       arName = .Range("B2:B" & lastrow).Value2
   End With
   
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planner")
        Set tbl = .ListObjects(1) ' or table name "Containers"
        a = tbl.ListColumns("AGREED_UNLOAD_HOUR").Index
        b = tbl.ListColumns("CONTAINER").Index
        For Each r In tbl.ListRows
            i = Application.Match(r.Range(, b), arName, 0)
            If Not IsError(i) Then
                r.Range(, a) = arID(i, 1)
                n = n + 1
            Else
                r.Range(, a) = "tba" ' or ""
            End If
        Next
   End With
   MsgBox n & " rows updated", vbInformation
   
End Sub
```